# Job execution on records supplied by database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I have a requirement to check all records in a table which is big (Around 1.5-2 million records). What I am doing is very simple, just get all the records and loop through one by one, and do things. I have a quartz job which will run every 2 minutes to check things.

ApplicationDetailCheckingJob.java

```
public class ApplicationDetailCheckingJob implements Job {

@Autowired
private DatabaseService databaseService;

@Value("${EnableJob}")
private boolean enableJob;

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
    if (enableJob) {
        try {
            LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "Started Checking...");
            //Get All Records
            List<Applications> allApplicationDetails = databaseService.getAllAppDetails();
                //Perform Check For Each Application
                allApplicationDetails.stream().forEachOrdered((app) -> {
                    //Check For Columns Values
                    //If SendTweet = 1, Send tweet to the Application's User
                    //If SendEmail = 1, Send Email to User
                    //If Send SMS = 1, Send SMS to User
                    //Rest is also similar procedures
                });
            LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "Finished checking.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogService.error(this.getClass().getName(), e);
        }
    } else {
        LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "ApplicationDetailChecking Job is Disabled");
    }
 }
}
```

DatabaseService.java

```
public List<Applications> getAllAppDetails() {

    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Applications";
    List<Applications> appDetails = defaultJdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Applications.class));

    LogService.info(this.getClass().getName(), "Number of records found = " + appDetails.size());

    return appDetails;
}
```

Can I improve these methods? Is there a better way?

If I use it in the live DB, I doubt the job can be finished before it's started again after 2 mins.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It would really help us if you could fill in what goes on in `allApplicationDetails.stream().forEachOrdered` instead of `//Do stuff`. You would benefit more from a review of the complete class, as there might be things in there specifically that are slowing down your job.

Comment: @Phrancis : In there i have to do a lot of checks for each column value. The table have around 22 Columns. So if i mention all of them it will be very big. Thats why i didn't write them. But i will edit the question and write some more comments.

Comment: OK, that would be an improvement, maybe show a few of the checks and comment that there are a lot more like that...

Comment: Sadly i cannot up-vote any replay cause of rep points. But in replies i received very useful tips

Answer (score 2):

For starters code-wise, I'm guessing you can try `allApplicationDetails.parallelStream()`.

Try to use more method references if possible as there are [potential performance advantages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277473/is-there-a-performance-benefit-to-using-the-method-reference-syntax-instead-of-l/285311#285311) to doing so.

Your `try-catch` is unusually wide, if an `Exception` is thrown from the first stream element, no further processing is done. Are you sure that is OK?

How is `jobExecutionContext` being used?

***Other more worthy considerations...***

> What I am doing is very simple, just get all the records and loop through one by one, and do things.

Can you batch some of these operations together? For example, do your 'downstream' libraries accept multiple inputs at once, or do they only send individually?

Do you really need to retrieve all 22 columns of 1.5 to 2 million records? Are there perhaps temporal columns on the table so that you can only fetch the most recently updated rows? Or a subset of the columns to minimize network traffic?

*The bigger question is...* can your actions be farmed off to an `ExecutionService` provider so that they can be performed asynchronously?

Simple in-memory processing of 1.5 to 2 million records in 2 minutes is relatively trivial with recent processing power. Having to incur network latencies (from emailing, <s>twitter-ing</s> tweeting, SMS-ing) is obviously going to introduce the 'timeout' issues that you are witnessing.

Most of these questions aren't really going to be covered by a code review (seeing how I've only dedicated four sentences to that), so perhaps you may want to drop by [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277473/is-there-a-performance-benefit-to-using-the-method-reference-syntax-instead-of-l/285311#285311) for some of the more hard-hitting questions I've asked.

Comment: I have inner try-catches which will return from there if any exception occurs. I havn't encountered any errors till now except NullPointer(Test DB). I have to process records individually. Table have AppID as primary Key. So need to check all of them. I dont need all columns. Max i need is 12. The table is updated constantly. I dont know how to do it asynchronously. Is it possible to take 50 record at once and then other 50 after and so on? If yes how can i do that?

Comment: If you have nested `try-catch` already, does that mean the 'big' one I highlighted is redundant? If so, my suggestion is to remove it. :) It might be worthwhile to actually see the lambda body, if you're comfortable (legally/technically) with sharing it...

Comment: I am not legally allowed to share the code. :(

Comment: @Rajkishan no worries. ;) Perhaps try reading up on [Executor Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) for a brief primer...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's suspicious to filter records in a program instead of the database. Especially if most of the records will not be used, it's better to let the database do the filtering. Databases are very good at that, and reduce the bandwidth between your application and the database server. Add some WHERE conditions to the query accordingly, to fetch only the records that are interesting to your job, for example:

```
... WHERE twitter is not null or email is not null ...
```

Secondly, it's suspicious to select all columns (`SELECT * FROM ...`). This is another way to waste bandwidth. It's recommended to select only the columns you actually need.

Comment: If i mention only specific column names. It gives error that sql statement is invalid. But my mapper class have only the rows i need.So i think it will only map required rows and rest will be ignored. Should i use a stored procedure instead and fetch only rows i need? will that make it better?

Comment: If your mapper is in java, then you're still filtering in code. You should filter in the database. Whether you filter in a simple SELECT or a stored proc, the end result will be more efficient. As for specifying column names, it looks like you have a syntax error, because conceptually it has to work. More than that, it's a recommended practice

Comment: If i write `SELECT SendTweet, ApplicationID FROM Applications`, it gives error that `unrecognized syntax at line-1 SendTweet` (part of exception)

Comment: Assuming that a column named "SendTweet" exists, with that exact speaking and upper-lower-casing, then perhaps there is a peculiarity of your object mapper / query runner. The technique has to work, by principle